# Ready vs ReadyDeprecated

Tags: javascript, rally

So, in my custom KanbanBoard app, I noticed lately that the READY green border has gone away.

I have started trying to debug, but cannot seem to understand what is going on.

On my board, users can click the READY icon and the border turns green, and in viewing the story it shows READY as true.  All is good.

When I hit F5, the green border goes away, but the ready field is still true.  Figured it was something I did, so removed all CSS overrides, but board didnt work still.

So was debugging, ran the HTML straight from desktop, the ready button isnt even on the card now.

Checked here, found that if the ready column is not available, the button wont show up.

So I used to have "Ready" in my getAdditionalFields function, and since I have tried "isReady", "ReadyDeprecated".  But cant seem to get to this field.

I checked the API Docs and queried from the documentation tried both READY and READYDEPRECATED and they return different result sets.

In the debugger I see a ReadDeprecated field, and no Ready field.  But viewing a story, I see a ready field that is boolean, and the card I set to true still shows true, though no green border...

Any suggestions on where to go with this?  Any background I am missing?  Pretty sure this was working before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent release Rally added support for Ready to all of our Artifacts. When we added the Ready flag in our 1.38 version of the API. When we did that we changed any custom fields named
Ready to be named ReadyDeprecated.

An easy fix for this is to change your App to use the current version of the API to the latest version of the WSAPI.

You can change AppSDK 1.0 Apps to use a newer version of the WSAPI by adding the apiVersion to the script include.

```
src="/apps/1.32/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.38"
```

The same can be accomplished in SDK 2.0 Apps using the wsapiVersion attribute.

```
src="/apps/2.0p/sdk.js?wsapiVersion=1.38"
```

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Guess I should have mentioned I am using 2.0p2.  When I changed it to 2.0p3 the page doesn't load: _https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/sdk.js?debug=true

Comment: Well... after looking a bit, i see you guys are on 2.0p5 !  Guess I need to read through some release notes, looks like artifactcard is gone :(

Comment: I have updated the response to show you how you can keep using the older version of the AppSDK. I would check out the newer cards in p5 and see if you like them. I think they are a huge improvement. If you want an example App using it I have one on my GitHub at https://github.com/ferentchak/CardboardCustomCard

Comment: Also let me know if you feel like sharing the App you built I always like seeing what people are making out there

Comment: thanks, i will check into it, i dont mind sharing the old one, it used a custom field for card status, very similar to the new Iteration Tracking Board (I think we spoke about in Texas Scrum conference).  I will post on a new thread on here though.  Will get your custom app, first step is to use our custom storystate instead of default one.